Shopify custom CSS
I have variants for my products that i would like to add a hover to change the colors but it has no class assigned. Is it better to edit the theme's files and add a class, if possible, or is there another way to assign the class?
The Input:
<input type="radio" form="AddToCartForm-template--17856642154724__main-8518139478244" checked="checked" value="Large 59&quot; x 47&quot;" data-index="option1" name="Size" data-variant-input="" class="" id="ProductSelect-template--17856642154724__main-8518139478244-option-size-Large+59%22+x+47%22"> 

I tried assigning the hover to other elements with no luck.

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

"or is there another way to assign the class?" - the better question would be, are there other ways to target the relevant element(s), than a class? But to be able to answer that, we need to see more of the context this element is in, and not just the element on its own.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Try this :


input[name="Size"] {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

input[name="Size"]:hover {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
<input type="radio" form="AddToCartForm-template--17856642154724__main-8518139478244" checked="checked" value="Large 59&quot; x 47&quot;" data-index="option1" name="Size" data-variant-input="" class="" id="ProductSelect-template--17856642154724__main-8518139478244-option-size-Large+59%22+x+47%22">



